# Android contact list with different phone numbers to call

Tags: android-contacts

I have made a contact list in android studio.Every item of the list contains a name, a phone number and an Image.what I want to do is when I click a item,it will start calling that phone number it contains.But I am unable to set different phone numbers for every item.what I could do is to parse a static number so whichever item I click it calls to that particular number.how can I do that?

```
 sazritListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0000"));
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a `ListView`, then you probably already implement a `getView` method in your `Adapter`.

So add a `setTag` line to your `getView` method, it should look something like this:

```
View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view;
   if (convertView != null) {
      view = convertView;
   } else {
      view = inflater.inflate(...) // Inflate a new view
   }
   MyObject obj = getItem(position);

   // set texts and images onto view

   view.setTag(obj.phoneNumber); // Tag the view with the phone-number
}
```

then in your `onItemLongClick` code:

```
String phoneNumber = (String) view.getTag();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
startActivity(intent);
return true;
```